# Accepting specific certificate with http-client-tls or tls?

Tags: haskell, ssl, certificate

I'm probably just overlooking something basic in the documentation of [http-client-tls](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-tls-0.2.2) and [tls](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls-1.2.9), but: how can I establish an HTTPS connection to a server and only accept *one particular* certificate, specified by me, that is potentially not in the system certificate store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ClientHooks](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls-1.2.8/docs/Network-TLS.html#t:ClientHooks). You can create a [TLSSettings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/connection-0.2.3/docs/Network-Connection.html#t:TLSSettings) value with that by using the [TLSSettings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/connection-0.2.3/docs/Network-Connection.html#v:TLSSettings) constructor, and then create a `ManagerSettings` using [mkManagerSettings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-tls-0.2.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-TLS.html#v:mkManagerSettings).

Answer (score 7):

I see that this is an old question, but I just spent some time writing code to do this and figured I'd post it here for posterity... and in the hopes of getting some code review from the community. Snoyman's comment is helpful, but there are so many code interdependencies here, and X.509 and TLS are so boil the ocean, that it's hard to debug and to know for sure that you're not screwing something up without digging pretty deep into the various libraries. I figured a more complete explanation with working code was in order.

Anyways, here's what I've come up with (this is a [stack script](https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script) so you can run it easily yourself) --

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --resolver lts-7.16 runghc -}

import qualified Data.ByteString           as B
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy         (ByteString)
import           Data.Default.Class           (def)
import           Data.String                  (fromString)
import           Data.X509.CertificateStore   (CertificateStore, readCertificateStore)
import           Network.HTTP.Client          (httpLbs, newManager, ManagerSettings)
import           Network.HTTP.Client.TLS      (mkManagerSettings)
import           Network.Connection           (TLSSettings(TLSSettings))
import qualified Network.TLS               as TLS
import qualified Network.TLS.Extra.Cipher  as TLS
import           System.Environment           (getArgs, getProgName)

managerSettings :: CertificateStore -> ManagerSettings
managerSettings store = mkManagerSettings settings Nothing
  where settings = TLSSettings params
        params   = (TLS.defaultParamsClient "" B.empty) {
                       TLS.clientUseServerNameIndication = True
                     , TLS.clientShared = def {
                           TLS.sharedCAStore = store
                       }
                     , TLS.clientSupported = def {
                           TLS.supportedCiphers = TLS.ciphersuite_default
                       }
                   }

get :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
get ca url = do
    mstore <- readCertificateStore ca
    case mstore of
        Just store -> do
            manager  <- newManager $ managerSettings store
            response <- httpLbs (fromString url) manager
            putStrLn (show response)
        Nothing    -> do
            putStrLn $ "error: invalid certificate store " ++ ca

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        ca:url:[] -> get ca url
        _         -> do
            name <- getProgName
            putStrLn $ "usage: " ++ name ++ " ca url"
```

A couple notes:

- The `TLS.sharedCAStore` settings is where the magic happens. If you want to *add* your CA to the system store (vs. using *only* your CA) you can load the system store using `getSystemCertificateStore` from [`System.X509`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/x509-system-1.6.4/docs/System-X509.html), then use [`Data.X509.CertificateStore`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/x509-store-1.6.2/docs/Data-X509-CertificateStore.html) to convert back and forth between `CertificateStore` and `[SignedCertificate]` to create a store with the system certificates along with your own.
- `TLS.defaultParamsClient` takes a hostname and server id, used for TLS server name indication (SNI), a TLS extension that allows a server to host multiple sites on a single IP (similar to how HTTP/1.1 host headers work). We don't necessarily know what to set this to when we're creating a manager. Fortunately, `Network.Connection` (used by `http-client-tls`) appears to [override whatever settings we use](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-connection/blob/master/Network/Connection.hs#L128), so it doesn't matter.
- The default for `TLS.supportedCiphers` is an empty list, so this setting is required (unless you turn off validation or something). `Network.Connection` [defaults to `ciphersuite_all`](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-connection/blob/master/Network/Connection.hs#L115) but that includes some "not recommended last resource cipher suites" so I opted to use `ciphersuite_default` instead.